# Celery add periodic task

Tags: celery

I've got the below code and I'm not sure why it doesn't work. It says `celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task Foo: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

If I take out the function `f` out from the `Foo` class, then it works.

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


app = Celery('test', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

class Foo:
    def f(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x

foo = Foo()
f = foo.f

f = app.task(f)

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def run_task(**kwargs):
    app.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='*/1'),
        f.s(),
        args=(60,),
        name='Foo'
    )
    app.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='*/2'),
        f.s(),
        args=(32,),
        name='Bar'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

To use class-based tasks, inherit from `app.Task`.

```
from celery import Celery, Task
from celery.schedules import crontab


app = Celery('test', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

class Foo(app.Task):
    def run(self, x: int, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return x

app.register_task(Foo())

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def run_task(**kwargs):
    app.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='*/1'),
        Foo().s(),
        args=(60,),
        name='Foo'
    )
    app.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='*/2'),
        Foo().s(),
        args=(32,),
        name='Bar'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to run it, all I'm getting is: `<ScheduleEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>`. I also notice that you imported `Task` but inherited from `app.Task`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, the app.Task was intentional -- I tried it both ways and both seemed to work but the `app.Task` is what is documented.

Comment: Very strange as it doesn't work on my side.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please. Do you have any error(s) in the output?